Unexpected "unsupported block type" error when creating AWS EC2 Spot instance with terraform
I'm trying to create EC2 Spot instance with terraform.
Following instruction of official document, I wrote following code.
resource "aws_instance" "my_spot_instance" {
  ami                         = "ami-05134c8ef96964280" # Ubuntu 24.04
  instance_type               = var.instance_type
  key_name                    = aws_key_pair.ai-key.key_name
  vpc_security_group_ids      = [aws_security_group.ai-web-sg.id]
  subnet_id                   = aws_subnet.ai-subnet-public.id
  associate_public_ip_address = true

  instance_market_options {
    market_type = "spot"
    spot_options {
      max_price = var.max_price
    }
  }

  root_block_device {
    volume_size = var.gp2_volume_size
    volume_type = "gp2"
  }

  tags = {
    Name    = "AI_spot_instance"
    Service = "ai"
  }
}

After running validation, I got following Unsupported block type error.
╷
│ Error: Unsupported block type
│
│   on main.tf line 30, in resource "aws_instance" "my_spot_instance":
│   30:   instance_market_options {
│
│ Blocks of type "instance_market_options" are not expected here.
╵

Version info
$ terraform --version
Terraform v1.9.5
on linux_amd64
+ provider registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/aws v4.67.0

I'm comparing my code with reference code, but struggling.
I really appreciate your help.

If your version of the AWS provider is correct, 4.67.0 doesn't have the property. Latest version is 5.64.0.

@Kaymaz Thank you for the comment, I found the property has introduced on 5.2.0. After upgrading, things went well!
